# Order of output changes in php echo

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

Hopefully this is a simple fix, for some reason when I run this. I am running wordpress and using the advanced custom fields plugin

```
echo "Tickets Start at CA$" . the_field('price');
```

I get this output

```
50Tickets Start at CA$
```

Instead of, what I want to happen which is

```
Tickets Start at CA$50
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong

Comment: `the_field()` i bet has an echo in it instead of a return

Comment: Would be helpful to see the source of that function - OP, can you add?

Comment: Sorry it is a wordpress plugin called advanced custom fields

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as @smith says [the_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) displays the value of the field. You want to use [get_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) instead which returns the value instead of displaying it.